# Jquery UI Widget Factory

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

```
$.widget( "app.serverTime", {
    _create: function () {
        $.get("/timestamp.php", function( data ) {
           this.timestamp = data.timestamp;
        })
    },

    getTime:function() {
       return this.timestamp;
    }
});


$(".clock").serverTime();
$(".clock").serverTime("getTime")
```

I have the above jQuery UI Widget when I call the getTime I am getting in the value I am expected but instead I am getting the jQuery Selector, when i set the value manually without using Ajax it works as expected.

Comment: Would be better to have a jsfiddle...

Comment: Cannot CrossDomain Ajax request

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is because of this. Inside the get function this not refer to the plugin calee object.

So save `this` reference and use it later like:

```
$.widget( "app.serverTime", {
    _create: function () {
        var _this=this;
        $.get("/timestamp.php", function( data ) {
           _this.timestamp = data.timestamp;
        })
    },

    getTime:function() {
       return this.timestamp;
    }
});
```

### EDIT

Consider that the `$.get` is async, so the timestamp property will be set when the `$.get` finish, but the code runs.

Concept:

```
$(".clock").serverTime();

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log($(".clock").serverTime("getTime"));
}, 5000);
```

So think about handle the async properly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/5pFkk/

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue! Will need to figure out how to implement it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small addition to [@Irvin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24752530/2685386): You can use `$.proxy` to easily change `this` within the function, and this is especially useful for working with the widget factory;

Additionally you *should* have a default value for the `timestamp` variable -- and should include an underscore in front of it's name (as that's the convention for "private" (pseudoprivate) fields -- I assume it's supposed to be private as you have a getter):

```
$.widget( "app.serverTime", {
    _create: function () {
        $.get("/timestamp.php", $.proxy(function( data ) {
           this._timestamp = data.timestamp;
        }, this))
    },
    _timestamp: "Tue Jul 15 2014 08:50:38 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)",

    getTime:function() {
       return this._timestamp;
    }
});
```

Comment: The value is not being overwritten!

Comment: If the GET request returns fine, it should; I suggest looking into that. Here's an example demo (minus the AJAX) http://jsfiddle.net/GkJPB/

Comment: The problem seems to be Ajax related since it is ASYNC the return is being triggered before the actual value being read

Comment: In that case you can attach an [always callback](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) `$.get().always(function() {/* do updates here */})`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/yft97sme/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("app.serverTime", {
    options: {
      server: "https://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip",
      showLabel: true,
      labelValue: "Server Time:"
    },
    _create: function() {
      var self = this;
      self.element.addClass("ui-server-time ui-widget");
      if (self.options.showLabel) {
        $("<label>", {
          class: "ui-server-time-label",
          style: "margin-right: 5px;"
        }).html(self.options.labelValue).appendTo(self.element);
      }
      $("<span>", {
        class: "ui-server-time-display"
      }).appendTo(self.element);
      $("<button>", {
        class: "ui-server-time-refresh",
        style: "margin-left: 5px;"
      }).html("Refresh").button({
        icon: "ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-s",
        showLabel: false
      }).click(function() {
        self.getTime();
      }).hide().appendTo(self.element);
      self.getTime();
    },
    _log: function(str) {
      console.log(Date.now(), str);
    },
    _serverTime: null,
    _collectTime: function() {
      var self = this;
      self.beforeGetTime();
      $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "get",
        url: this.options.server,
        success: function(results) {
          self._log("Collected Time: " + results.unixtime);
          self._setTime(results);
        }
      });
    },
    _setTime: function(obj) {
      this._log("Time Setter");
      this._serverTime = obj
    },
    _getTime: function() {
      this._log("Time Getter");
      var dt = new Date(this._serverTime.datetime);
      $(".ui-server-time-display", this.element).html(dt.toString());
      $(".ui-server-time-refresh", this.element).show();
      return this._serverTime;
    },
    beforeGetTime: function() {
      this._log("Before Get Time");
    },
    getTime: function() {
      this._collectTime();
      this._delay(this._getTime, 500);
    },
    _destroy: function() {
      this.element.children().remove();
      this.element.removeclass("ui-server-time");
    }
  });

  $(".clock").serverTime({
    showLabel: false
  });
});
```

If you run the GET in the creation of the widget, it will show the Server Time from that moment. It will also delay the creation if the server is slow to respond. I would suggest moving the collection of the time to it's own function. This way you can call it whenever you want.

Assuming your PHP Script might return a different value, you may need to adjust the result handling.

Comment: Some further development: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/yft97sme/147/